# Kettle compile Jar with dependencies

Tags: java, jar, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

Pentaho/Kettle: Instead of running code from the code box in the "User defined Java Class", I am trying to compile it into a Jar, and run the jar file from the "User defined Java Class". I do this because my Java projects are too big, and in order to increase modularity. However, there are some problems with dependencies. Some methods are not available in the libraries, whereas there are some which are available in multiple libraries.

Zip file of the project I am trying to compile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H-RGGvH-h3zvLnF3qIVVIHnnB4vtwKvN/view?usp=sharing.

Code of the Gradle dependencies I am using:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-core', 
version: '3.1.2'

compile group: 'pentaho-kettle', name: 'kettle-core', version: '7.0.0.3-62'
compile group: 'pentaho-kettle', name: 'kettle-sdk-database-plugin', version: '7.0.0.0-25'
compile group: 'pentaho-kettle', name: 'kettle-sdk-step-plugin', version: '7.0.0.0-25'
compile group: 'pentaho-kettle', name: 'kettle-ui-swt', version: '7.0.0.3-62'

compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.16'

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

full code

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


import be.ibridge.kettle.core.exception.KettleException;
import be.ibridge.kettle.trans.step.StepDataInterface;
import be.ibridge.kettle.trans.step.StepMetaInterface;
import be.ibridge.kettle.core.*;

/**
 * @author Michiel
 */


public class JavaExampleCheckRegex {

private Pattern p = null;
private FieldHelper fieldToTest = null;
private FieldHelper outputField = null;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) 
throws KettleException
{
    Object[] r = getRow();

    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    // prepare regex and field helpers
    if (first){
        first = false;

        String regexString = getParameter("regex");
        p = Pattern.compile(regexString);

        fieldToTest = get(Fields.In, getParameter("test_field"));
        outputField = get(Fields.Out, "result");
    }

    r = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());

    // Get the value from an input field
    String test_value = fieldToTest.getString(r);

    // test for match and write result
    if (p.matcher(test_value).matches()){
        outputField.setValue(r, Long.valueOf(1));
    }
    else{
        outputField.setValue(r, Long.valueOf(0));
    }

    // Send the row on to the next step.
    putRow(data.outputRowMeta, r);

    return true;
    }

}
```

Screenshot of some methods it cannot detect (in red): 
[image: Undetected methods]

Screenshot of some methods that are available in multiple libraries: 
[image: Methods available in multiple libraries]

EDIT: Manually adding ALL of the Jars from \data-integration\lib\ does not work either.

Comment: Please do not post code i screen-shots. Just copy the code into the clipboard, paste it into your question and mark it as code.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. This question is not regarding code, but the missing of dependencies and it's implications: methods not being found and turning red. If I would have copy-pasted the code, you would not be able to see the corresponding missing methods turning red. The final screenshot is added to make clear that some method names are available in multiple libraries, so I do not know which one is the right one.

Comment: Furthermore, the full code and gradle file are provided in a zip file. The reason I use a zip file is because this question is regarding the (dependencies of the) entire project, and not single code snippets.

Comment: And how long will the zip be available on files.fm? Stackoverflow questions are for "eternity". Therefore you should prevent external links on Stackoverflow in general. And code in screenshots is not accessible for the search engine.

Comment: I know what the power of plain text is. If you look at my other questions and answers, you will see that they are plain text. However, the only relevant keywords for this particular problem are "kettle", "jar" , "dependency", etc. Furthermore, solving this problem requires you to download the zip anyway. Your point about eternity is valid though. I changed the link to a Google drive link.

Comment: I replaced the screenshot of the Gradle file with code as well, as I can imagine people are searching for it.

Comment: I think Robert talks about your code : the screenshoot. If it were a text rather than a image, it would allow me to copy/paste my response too.

Comment: I changed the screenshot of the dependencies to a code snippet of the dependencies. Once again, the point of the screenshot of the code with the red methods, is to show some example methods that are not found in any of the dependencies. And as I've said before, you need to download the zip file of the project anyways in order to find out about the dependencies.

Comment: Anyways, I will provide the full code snippet if that helps you.

Comment: Chiel. There is no point in unzipping the whole project. Just extract  a **minimal** example so that we can understand your issue and you how to solve the problem.

Comment: I already provided the minimalistic, complete, and reproducible example. Namely, the gradle and the code. I hope you will find a solution ;-)

Comment: @Chiel Are you able to get the corresponding imports for the methods in the red?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the methods in red ?

It is not because the file is on the classpath that the class knows it needs to import them.

That would also fix your multiple library issue, because the import specify the full path name.

```
import be.ibridge.kettle.core.exception.KettleException;
...

public class JavaExampleCheckRegex{
...
}
```

Comment: You chose one of the two available imports which could be fine. However, I still do not know which KettleException to pick: the one from Pentaho, or the one from Kettle.

Comment: Some methods do not get a popup of an available import. For example, the setOutputDone() method. See screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/vs1BKMv

Comment: I am talking about replacing your first line `import be.ibridge.kettle.core.*;` by explicit `import be.ibridge.kettle.core.exception.KettleException;` to resolve multiple dependence.

Comment: I am also talking about adding all the needed dependence below your first line. Of course to do that easily you need an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans,...). And I cannot help you more because my IDE does understand text, not screenshots.

Comment: It should be the Pentaho exception not the kettle one as you've imported pentaho jars.

Comment: JavaExampleCheckRegex  most probably must extend some AbstractStep or something like BaseStep.